# Bokeh の tooltip の設定の仕方を教えてください

Tags: python, bokeh

```
TOOLTIPS = [
    ("(時刻,工程)", "($x, $y)"),
]
```

でtooltipの設定を行いました。
`p = figure(tooltips=TOOLTIPS)`でグラフ設定を行っています。

```
p.line(・・・・)
show(p)
```

でグラフは作れました。問題は、TOOLTIPSの$xです。
x軸のデータの型は、datetime型です。$xでTOOLTIPするととても大きな値が出てしまいます。
$xをうまく変更すれば、2019-05-31 21:59 といった表示に変更できないものでしょうか？
ご指導よろしくお願いいたします。

以下にソースコード追加

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta as dtdelta

import pandas

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, reset_output

# 出力設定
reset_output()

#ツールチップ
output_file("graph.html")
TOOLTIPS = [
    ("(時刻,工程)", "($x, $y)"),
]

p = figure(tooltips=TOOLTIPS, plot_width=1200, plot_height=1200,x_axis_location="above" ,x_axis_type = "datetime",x_axis_label="時刻", y_axis_label="工程")

x_dtlist1 = [dt(2019,2,1,8,15,00),dt(2019,2,1,8,30,00),dt(2019,2,1,8,35,00),dt(2019,2,1,8,40,00),dt(2019,2,1,8,45,00)]
x_dtlist2 = [dt(2019,2,1,9,15,00),dt(2019,2,1,9,30,00),dt(2019,2,1,9,35,00),dt(2019,2,1,9,40,00),dt(2019,2,1,9,45,00)]
x_dtlist3 = [dt(2019,2,1,10,15,00),dt(2019,2,1,10,30,00),dt(2019,2,1,10,35,00),dt(2019,2,1,10,40,00),dt(2019,2,1,10,45,00)]
y_dtlist = [0,1,1,2,2]
p.line(x_dtlist1, y_dtlist)
p.line(x_dtlist2, y_dtlist)
p.line(x_dtlist3, y_dtlist)
show(p)
```

#### 環境

- bokeh v1.0.2

Comment: 差支えなければbokehのバージョンと、実際に動かなかったソースコードを載せていただきたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 解決方法

以下のコードで、`2019-05-31 21:59`というフォーマットで日時をHoverToolに表示できます。

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, reset_output
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

# データ作成
df = pd.DataFrame([{"x":1, "y":2, "date": datetime.datetime.now()}])

hover_tool = HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ("(x,y)", "($x, $y)"),
        ( "date", "@date{%F %R}"), # 'date'フィールドを'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'でフォーマット
    ],
    formatters={
        'date': 'datetime', # 'data'フィールドを'datetime'フォーマットにする
    },
    mode='mouse'
)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)
p = figure(tools=[hover_tool], x_axis_label="x", y_axis_label="y")
p.circle(x="x", y="y", source=source)
show(p)
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, reset_output
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

# データ作成
df = pd.DataFrame([{"x":1, "y":2, "date": datetime.datetime.now()}])

hover_tool = HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ("(x,y)", "($x, $y)"),
        ( "date", "@date{%F %R}"), # 'date'フィールドを'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'でフォーマット
    ],
    formatters={
        'date': 'datetime', # 'data'フィールドを'datetime'フォーマットにする
    },
    mode='mouse'
)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)
p = figure(tools=[hover_tool], x_axis_label="x", y_axis_label="y")
p.circle(x="x", y="y", source=source)
show(p)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 解説

> $xでTOOLTIPするととても大きな値が出てしまいます。

`$x`はカーソルのx座標値を表すので、データの値を表示されません。

> x-coordinate under the cursor in data space

https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html 引用

`HoverTool`の生成部分では、「`date`という列が、`datetime`フォーマットで、具体的には"%F %R"である」ことを宣言しています。
"%F"や"%R"の意味は[DatetimeTickFormatter](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.formatters.DatetimeTickFormatter)で定義されています。

詳しくは以下を参照してください。
https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#formatting-tooltip-fields

#### 実行環境

- Python 3.7
- bokeh 1.1.0
- pandas 0.24.2

#### 追記：x軸を日付にしたグラフ

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{"date":datetime.date(2019,5,1), "sales": 100},{"date":datetime.date(2019,6,1), "sales": 200}])
source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)

hover_tool = HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ("(x,y)", "($x, $y)"),
        ("date", "@date{%F %R}"), # '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
        ("sales", "@sales")
    ],
    formatters={
        'date': 'datetime', # 'data'フィールドを'datetime'フォーマットにする
    },
    mode='mouse'
)

p = figure(x_axis_label="date", y_axis_label="sales", x_axis_type="datetime", tools=[hover_tool])
p.line(x="date", y="sales", source=source)

show(p)
```

#### 質問者様のコードを修正

```py
hover_tool = HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ("(時刻,工程)", "(@x{%F %R}, $y)"),
    ],
    formatters={
        'x': 'datetime',
    },
    mode='mouse'
)

p = figure(tools=[hover_tool], plot_width=1200, plot_height=1200,x_axis_location="above" ,x_axis_type = "datetime",x_axis_label="時刻", y_axis_label="工程")
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご回答のx軸はfloat型等ですが、上記質問のx軸はdatetime型です。従って、グラフ上でx軸は時刻になっており期待通りになってはいるものの、オンマウスしたtooltipの$xが時刻になっておらず（当然なのですが）困っております。$x{%F %R}といったことが出来ればいいのですが、出来ないようで困っております。何か方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: x軸を日付にしたグラフを表示するコードを追記しました。このコードではダメでしょうか？
今動かそうしているコードを、質問文に追記していただけるとありがいたいです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。お手数をおかけします。質問文にソースを追加いたしました。本当はx_dtlist1～x_dtlist100位まであり、for文でp.lineを100個作っております。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: bokeh のバージョンは、1.0.2でした。上記追加したソースコードは、ジュピタ－ノートブックで確認済みです。失礼いたしました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 回答に追記しました。いかがでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指導いただいた通りしました。期待通りの出力をすることが出来ました。

Comment: 解決できてよかったです。解決しましたら「回答を承認」（緑のチェックマーク）をお願いします。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer