# bokeh の tooltip で　@foo,@bar　とは何でしょうか？

Tags: python, bokeh

bokeh の tooltip で　@foo,@bar　はどのような使い方をするのでしょうか？
ご指導よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: たぶん https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/55411/ に関する内容だと思いますが、もう少しサンプルコードがあった方がよいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    tooltips=[
        ("(x,y)", "($x, $y)"),
        ("date", "@date{%F %R}"), # '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
        ("sales", "@sales")
    ]
```

`@`から始まるフィールドは、`ColumnDataSource`のcolumnと紐づいています。

> Field names that begin with @ are associated with columns in a ColumnDataSource. For instance the field name "@price" will display values from the "price" column whenever a hover is triggered. If the hover is for the 17th glyph, then the hover tooltip will correspondingly display the 17th price value.

https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#basic-tooltips 引用